# i need to get value from loop in database for the next calculate

Tags: java

Thats result just give me 11,8,9. I want to sum become 28. Then use the result into the next my calculate  11/28=0,39 and 8/28=0,28 and 9/28=0,32 . Then show final result. Help me

```
    try{


      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hitung1","root","");
      String sql = ("select angka1,angka2 from tabel1 ");
      PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

      while(rs.next()){
          double a=rs.getInt("angka1");
          double b=rs.getInt("angka2");
          double d=b+a;

          System.out.println("" +d);

      } }
   catch(Exception e){}
    e
```

Comment: Based on the code, you know how to declare variables, how to add them together, presumably how to divide them too, and also how to print them, so I really don't see what problem you could be having with just doing what you want to do. Well, okay, I see maybe 1 or 2 possible non-trivial parts, but you really should try to write some code and then ask about the specific part that's not working the way you expect instead of asking us to finish your code for you.

Comment: Which part are you getting stuck? Not clear